Using Global Entry after ticket has been booked with TSA PreCheck KTN
The situation:
I booked a flight (USA to Canada to France to Canada to US) using our TSA PreCheck issued KTNs.  We then were approved for Global Entry and have received our PASSIDs.
Do I now need to contact the airline (Air Canada) and have them change anything on our ticket or does my TSA issued KTN provide me PreCheck for our US to Canada flight AND Global Entry access for our return flight home?  IIRC, the customs agent said our existing KTN would work for both until it expired then our PSSID would replace that number and provide us PreCheck, etc.

Global entry has nothing to do with your ticket or the airline. If you have global entry - you just go to the globally entry line and use the machines.
For the TSA pre-check in Canada you might want to carry the physical card with you, I've been asked to present it on one occasion (in Calgary) and was told it's a requirement there.

You need to use the Trusted Traveler Number that's on the back of your Global Entry card.  See for example https://www.recess4grownups.com/wp-content/uploads/Trusted-Traveler-Global-Entry-Card-gov-ws-768x478.jpg
If that's the same number than the one issued by TsaPre, you are good. You can always add/change the  KTN on the "manage your booking" page on the airline's website. You can also add/change it at check in but this can be problematic in France. I had multiple check in agents that didn't know what a KTN was and also did not know how to add it to the reservation so it's safer if you do it yourself.
A good indicator that your KTN worked is seeing "TSAPre" on your boarding pass.
As far as I know, Global Entry is tied to your passport number (not the KTN) so technically it should work without. But you won't get TSAPre without it.
